# I want to simplify the mesh of the ornamental design on this bench, while still keeping the general look

Tags: mesh

Making a model of the Titanic. Want people to be able to "walk" around it at some point. I've mentioned this in previous posts.

I've got benches throughout the decks and I wanted to try to get the ornamental detail on the arms, but I worry that it's adding unnecessary geometry to my model. Is it possible to simplify the mesh, while still getting the general look?

Edit: Forgot to mention I've tried the Limited Dissolve and the Decimate modifiers. The current result is what I thought was the happy medium between keeping the shape and simplifying the mesh using those features.

[image: Titanic Bench]